# Are global variables and static variables bad for memory?

Tags: ios, swift

I can create a variable that is accessible anywhere in the program by different methods, for example :-

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
static var flightJson = "123"
}
```

```
var flightJson = 9
class ViewControllerX: UIViewController {
//
}
```

```
struct storedJson
{
  static var flightJson = 1234
}
```

and i can access all of these in any class

```
class ViewControllerZ: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print(ViewController.flightJson)
        print(flightJson)
        print(storedJson.flightJson)

    }
}
```

And now my question is, are there any difference between these or are like end being just the same and keep on occupying memory space until the app is terminated ?

I do know that global variables are against OOP and MVC.
The reason for asking this question is that, i am using `SOAP API` and i have to send a massive `Json` back to the server after changing a few stuff in the json. I get the `Json` on the second page of the app and i am using it on the 3rd , 4th and 7th page and then on the 8th page i have to edit and add some extra information and then sent it back to the server.

Currently, i just create a static variable using the first method and keep it until the end.

Is this a bad practise and the most important question is that, if there a lot of such variables, will they end up being memory hog?

Edit : A bit of clarification :  I use codables to get the api stuff and then i just transfer the `Json Object` i want into this variable and then on the 8th page i access a particular array/object through this variable and do the necessary changes and then i convert this variable into `Json` and then i send it back.
Here there is no issue of reducing code readability as i/other developers can see that this variable was from some particular `ViewController`.

Comment: A comment on the second option, `var a`, this is for me a big No to have a variable that doesn’t belong to any type. The code will be hard to understand and what happens if you create a property or local variable with the same name, it could become a nightmare to maintain and troubleshoot

Comment: @JoakimDanielson How about, lets say i / anyone can define the variable with some proper clarity(Ofcourse its still a nightmare) but what i really want to know is that, are all of these endup being the same in terms of memory management and usage ? (discarding the code readability part)

Comment: They should all use the same amount of memory

Comment: If you have a variable that you want to access from anywhere, never put it in ViewController. ViewControllers should not store anything that is not used to display some views. Instead, create a separate class: model, service, etc, and store your static variables there.

Comment: @KirilS. So a struct on a different swift file is the better option? Oh and the stuff from the ``Json`` is being displayed on the above mentioned pages (views)

Comment: Structures are copied when passed from object to object, they are not a good option to store something long term. Usually people use `class` for variables, and `enum` for constants

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that all of these end up working the same way, its just that some have better readability and makes it easier to search and find where a variable or object is from.

Option 1 and Option 3 would be a good way to use global variables !